# Combination Seeking with Excel

Tags: excel, optimization

I have a question essentially about how to solve a problem in excel somewhat of a "pick the best option" type of question.

Setup: I have a list of options, say option 1a, 1b, 1c... 2a, 2b, 2c, etc. up to 6a, 6b... The options have sub-options, lets say x,y and z which are unique to their parent option and cannot change. Each parent option is unique, ex. 1a is not the same as 2a or 3a - and 1a is not the same as 1b or 1c.

I can pick one option from each number, i.e. i have 6 separate choices to make and an example combination at final would be: 1a,2b,3a,4c,5d,6a - however not 1a, 1b, 5a, 3a, 1c, 4c, 3a because it is required to pick one each of 1-6. The values of x, y and z will be added together (example: the x from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 will be added) to yield a *total* value for x, y and z from all 1-6 combined.

The question is as follows:
I want to maximize one of the 'sub-options', lets say x. How would I perform this selection using excel? Is there a way to do this reasonably? Additionally, if I wanted to maximize x -and- z would the method suggested by whoever responds to this be able to do such?

I've had a number of math courses so it rather bothers me that I can't figure this out. Mostly I know that maximization of functions is does with derivatives, but this idea of "picking" options instead of having an actual funciton seems to be confusing me.

I found a somewhat similar post, [Excel Solver Using Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148132/excel-solver-using-strings), using binary constraints to denote "on" or "off" for an option, but I'm not quite sure how I would employ the method described to this specific type of problem. I have a feeling this is a problem of determining the appropriate constraints to use for my specific problem, and so I'm looking for  advice.

As a final point, I would prefer to avoid any VBA coding, as I am not well versed in the language and don't really have a lot of time to dedicate to such an undertaking right now.

Apologies for the long-winded question, it's my first time asking a question on here so I wanted to be as thorough as possible.

Thanks in advance to anyone that helps out!

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand this correct, you have 6 Options 1-6. Every Option has 3 "Children" a,b,c and each of these "Children" has 3 Values x,y,z. Since you don't have any constraints on how to choose, just choose the child of every option with the biggest x value. So for example, consider Option 1, just check which x value is the largest of 1a, 1b and 1c. And so on.

Would be helpful if you would share how you stored this in excel.